# MySQL code error

Tags: mysql, sql

How would i rewrite this for MySQL?

```
select id, name
From student
Except
Select id, name
from student natural join takes
where year < 2009
```

Comment: I'm more so asking how could i rewrite this for MySQL sorry for the wording.

Comment: Not addressing the question directly, since it looks like the first answer covers that, but `natural join` can be a good recipe for a timebomb; all that needs to happen is somewhere down the line for a column to be be added to one table that already exists in the other (and should not be used for joins), or for a column that is necessary for the join to make sense to be removed from one table or the other. The most insidious part is that such changes will not break/invalidate your query, just "corrupt" the results, potentially resulting in a cascade of problems without warnings.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `except`, use [`not in`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/all-subqueries.html) for MySQL

```
select id, name
from student
where id not in (
   select id
   from student natural join takes
   where year < 2009)
```